# Geometry problem, find lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Here's my problem:
[image]

I know the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and the line length $a + b$. I need to find the lengths $a$ and $b$ and the height of the triangle. I came up with the identity $$\frac{a}{b} = {\tan\alpha \over \tan\beta}$$, but I don't know what to do next. Can you help?

Comment: if I understand what you are saying..you already have $a+b$ and $a/b$. that's 2 equations with 2 vars.

Comment: Hint:
$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta}$ is not correct.

Comment: @JohnJoy Right, it is the other way tan alpha / tan beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first find the height $h$ by the relation $$\frac h{\tan \alpha} + \frac h{\tan \beta} = a + b \implies h = \frac{a+b}{\cot \alpha + \cot \beta}.$$

now use $$a = h\cot \alpha, b = h\cot \beta. $$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{\tan \alpha }{\tan \beta }$$

assume $S=a+b$
$$\frac{S-a}{a}=\frac{\tan \alpha }{\tan \beta }$$
then 
$$a=\frac{S\tan \beta}{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}$$
$$\tan \alpha=\frac{h}{a}$$
hence
$$h=a\tan \alpha$$

Comment: doesn't $h=b\tan\alpha$ imply that $a=b$?

Comment: @JohnJoy thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Law of Sines:
$$\frac{|\overline{CB}|}{\sin A} = \frac{|\overline{CA}|}{\sin B} = \frac{|\overline{AB}|}{\sin C} \quad \left(= \frac{a+b}{\sin(A+B)}\;\right)$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
a &= |\overline{CA}| \cos A = \frac{(a+b)\cos A \sin B}{\sin(A+B)} \\[6pt]
b &= |\overline{CB}| \cos B = \frac{(a+b)\sin A \cos B}{\sin(A+B)}
\end{align}$$